# Any conflicts when creating two User accounts (with different privileges) but the same Apple ID?

Tags: icloud, apple-id, user-account, administrator

I've set up iMac A with an Admin User account {501}, a User account {512}, and also three "sharing only" accounts {502, 503, 504} for networking with iMac B.

I've set up iMac B with an Admin User account {501} and three User accounts {502, 503, 504}.

**The Admin {501} AND User {512} account on iMac A; the Admin {501} account on iMac B all use the same Apple ID.**

On iMac A User account {512} in "Users&Groups Preferences" > "Advanced Options" the AppleID Alias for my Apple ID will not populate the "Aliases" field. AppleID aliases start with `com.apple.idms.appleid.prd.`. Yet, both iMac A and iMac B Admin accounts {501} have the same AppleID Alias.

I have tried to add that same AppleID Alias to my User account {512} on iMac A (since it uses the same AppleID as the Admin account), but it's rejected. It seems the AppleID alias is a device specific ID. If I remove it from one user and add it to the other it accepts it, but it can't be used for more than one user on one machine even if both accounts use the same AppleID.

**With that background information... the question: Maybe there is an incompatibility or limitation having two user accounts on the same machine using the same AppleID?** Specifically when it comes to networking. I believe the AppleID Alias allows a user to select "Connect Using AppleID" when networking.

Also, can anyone who has used their AppleID on two computers confirm that their AppleID Alias is the same?

Since I am in my User account 99% of the time it's been convenient to keep some information synced with my Admin account using iCloud — email, messages, notes, etc are all synced. Is there any reason it would be more appropriate to use separate Apple IDs for my Admin and User accounts??

Please refrain from telling me, "Don't make changes to those settings". I am looking for responses that answer my questions. Thank you.

Comment: I have used the same Apple ID on 3 different Macs and even more users, most of them using 501, 502 and many iPhones.. no problem. Can you focus on the rejection case?

Comment: @Pierre ALBARÈDE I am asking about the same Apple ID used for two accounts on the same machine. One is an admin and one is a user. “Rejection case”?  The issue is more about networking using “connect using AppleID” when one user can’t use the AppleID alias- because two users on the same machine can’t have the same AppleID alias.

Comment: I have just tried again.  It works.  HTTP does not know user id or privilege on local machine.  The concept does not even has sense on a mobile phone,  I can connect from any user of any machine provided the right credentials,

Comment: Could it be a problem with strong authentification?